# Change of variable involving limits

Tags: measure-theory

In class we learned the following change of variable formula

> Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{A})$ two measurable spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a measurable map. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X,\mathcal{F})$, then we define the pushforward measure $f_*\mu$ on $(Y,\mathcal{A})$ as
>   $$ f_*\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A)),\forall A\in\mathcal{A}$$
>   Let $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative measurable function, then
>   $$\int_{f^{-1}(A)}g(f(x))\mu (dx)=\int_Ag(y)f_*\mu(dy)$$

Now I wonder about the following. Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{A})$ be two metric spaces. Moreover we have a sequence $(f_n)$ such that $f_n:X\to Y$ and $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Note we assume convergence for every $x$ not $\mu$-a.s. and we also know $(f_n)_*\mu\to f_*\mu$ weakly. Moreover let $g:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous non negative functions. Hence we can write
$$\int_Xg(f(x))\mu(dx)=\int_X\lim_ng(f_n(x))\mu(dx)$$

Can we now apply the change of variable formula and if so, what would be the result? Is it
$$\int_X\lim_ng(f_n(x))\mu(dx)=\int_Yg(y)\lim_n[(f_n)_*\mu(dy)]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the assumption that the $f_n$ are measurable (otherwise the pushforward measure does not make sense).

Then $f$ is also measurable as a pointwise limit of measurable functions.

Also, since $g$ is continuous $\lim_n g(f_n(x))=g(f(x))$ for $x\in X$. Therefore

$$\int_X \lim_n g(f_n(x)) \mu(dx)=\int_{f^{-1}(Y)} g(f(x)) \mu(dx) = \int_Y g(y) f_*\mu(dy)$$

We are just applying the change of variable formula for $f$. No limit magic.

I would be careful with writing $\lim_n (f_n)_*\mu = f_*\mu$. There is various modes of convergence for measures and depending on which one you choose this to mean, there is additional assumptions on $f_n$ that you need to conclude convergence of the pushforward measures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We know in fact $(f_n)_*\mu\to f_*\mu$ weakly.I would like to have also a limit on the space $Y$

Comment: @math: That needs more than just pointwise convergence (c.f. dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: Can you explain this further?

Comment: @math: I assume by weak you actually mean weak-*, i.e. $\int g (f_n)_*\mu \rightarrow \int g f_*\mu$ for all $g$ in some class of functions, say bounded continuous. The LHS is just $\int g(f_n(x)) \mu(dx)$, the RHS $\int g(f(x)) \mu(dx)$, to conclude convergence we need the additional assumption that $g(f_n(x))\le h(x)$ for some $\mu$-integrable $h$. The dominated convergence theorem is sharp in the sense that without this assumption there are counterexamples.

Comment: One small question. If we know that we can write $g(x)=\lim_n g_n(x_n)$ for every sequence $x_n\to x$. Can we apply the change of variable in this form: $\int_X g(f(x))\mu(dx)=\int_X\lim_ng_n (f_n(x))\mu(dx)=\int_Y \lim_ng_n(y)(f_n)_*\mu(dy)$

Comment: @math: Again the same issue, you're talking about the limit of the sequence of pushforward measures.